# Importing rotated text from a PDF table such as with tabula-py in python

Tags: python, pdf, tabula-py

Is there a way to import rotated text from a PDF table such as with tabula-py in python?

I realize I can just rename the column headers in this case, but I was wondering if there is a way to set a parameter for importing rotated text.  I don't see any mention of rotation in the readthedocs for tabula-py and haven't found other packages that would do this yet either (although I did see a mention of rotating an entire page- which doesn't fit this use case exactly as renaming the columns would be easier).

Example:

```
import tabula

list_df = tabula.read_pdf(
    'https://sos.oregon.gov/elections/Documents/statistics/G22-Daily-Ballot-Returns.pdf',
    pages=3
)

list_df[0]
```

[image: Screen Capture of Result and PDF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Francesco mentioned, there is a particular way in which camelot is a better than tabula-py, since camelot finds the rotated text.

It was a difficult process to install camelot, so I thought to share some of my learnings here.

1. Dependency for camelot: ghostwriter
   https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install-deps.html

For a mac `brew install ghostscript tcl-tk` and then troubleshoot any errors (many errors for me, but after copy-pasting each error, there was gold at the end of the rainbow).

2. Overview of camelot install https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install.html

On a mac:
`pip install "camelot-py[cv]"`

The documentation page currently actually says [base] rather than [cv], but above in the comments it says [cv] (and stack overflow articles say [cv]).

3. In python (if you are using jupyter notebook, restart the notebook kernel)

With the following, the rotated column headers are read in just fine.

```
import camelot
tables = camelot.read_pdf(
    'https://sos.oregon.gov/elections/Documents/statistics/G22-Daily-Ballot-Returns.pdf',
    pages='all')
tables[3].df
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried using camelot and it correctly reads the rotated text in the columns header: [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q2ovZ1N2SKHv1M9da5sqjxw4TN_rny0E/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106145905174590804650&rtpof=true&sd=true) is the result.

Comment: Thanks for the motivation. I'm going to post how to do this in the answer section.